# Install keyboard on Android Wear

Tags: keyboard, input-methods, text-input, android-wear

I've got an Android wear device.(the LG G Watch) And I installed some APK apps via ADB. How can I install a keyboard on Android Wear that I can use in apps I installed with ADB? I tried plugging in a keyboard to the Android Wear but it didn't help. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there's a version of [Minuum keyboard for wear](http://support.minuum.com/knowledgebase/articles/394385-minuum-on-android-wear) – if you want a keyboard directly on the device. You can see it in action [on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxWPe4HiMdA) (second half of it) – or check the [Minuum Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/minuumproject).

Comment: @Izzy I know but I cant use it in other apps :-(

Comment: Ah – OK, I couldn't check (have no Wear device). Sorry to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I can send text input to my Android Wear device this way:

1. `adb shell`
2. `input text <your_text>`

Hope it will help someone else!

More info here: http://blog.rungeek.com/post/42456936947/sending-keyboard-input-via-adb-to-your-android